# bitbucket curl PUT command issue

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to create a new file in Bitbucket:

```
curl -u user:password -X PUT "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:PORT/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEST1/repos/demo1" -F "filename.ext=@filename.ext"
```

It looks okay but does not work.
What am I missing? How can I debug this?

Comment: Version 1.0 of the api doesn't support adding files. Try version 2:  https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src#post

Comment: I have a bitbucket server. I beieve it does not support rest api 2.0

Comment: What version of bit bucket server?